# Ubuntu 12.04 Unable to install phpmyadmin after installing mysqlnd

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've recently removed the php mysql extension and replaced it with mysqlnd.

While removing mysql phpmyadmin was removed also, and now i'm unable to install it again.

Output from

`apt-get update`

`apt-get install phpmyadmin`

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php but it is not installable
              Depends: php-cli but it is not installable
              Depends: php-mysql but it is not installable
              Depends: php-json but it is not installable
              Depends: php-mbstring but it is not installable
              Depends: php-xml but it is not installable
              Recommends: php-curl but it is not installable
              Recommends: php-gd but it is not installable
              Recommends: php-bz2 but it is not installable
              Recommends: php-zip but it is not installable
              Recommends: php-tcpdf but it is not installable
```

php version is 5.5.36

Comment: Did you updated your package list before trying to install `phpmyadmin`? `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: yes i did - ive updated question